How to detect when the app is removed from recent apps in Flutter?
I'm trying to detect when my Flutter app is removed from the list of recent apps. I attempted to use AppLifecycleState.detached in combination with WidgetsBindingObserver, but it seems that detached state is never triggered. Below is the code I used:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      // App was closed from recent tabs
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello, World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

However, AppLifecycleState.detached is never triggered when I remove the app from the recent apps list. How can I detect this scenario correctly? Is there an alternative approach or a solution to this problem?

To detect when a Flutter app is removed from the recent apps list, you can override the onTaskRemoved method in the Android MainActivity. This method is triggered when the app is swiped away from the recent apps, allowing you to execute custom code.

That sounds like an answer, @Bob.

Hi @Bob, Thanks for your response. Is there another way that could work? Since I had to do something when the app was closed from a specific screen alone. Not from all the screen. Your suggestion may work if I need to do something while closing the app from recent apps every time.

@Gowtham your code is mostly correct, but there is a misunderstanding regarding the AppLifecycleState.detached state. The detached state is not triggered when the app is closed from the recent apps menu. Instead, it is used when the app is detached from the host view but may still be running in the background.
You should monitor the AppLifecycleState.paused state, which occurs when the app is no longer visible, or the AppLifecycleState.inactive state, which occurs when the app is transitioning between foreground and background.

@Bob, For instance, if the user exits the application, I want to remove certain information. When the user opens the app from recent apps again after I take the necessary action while the state is AppLifecycleState.paused, the data won't be accessible correctly.

AppLifecycleState.detached is not always reliably triggered across all devices. If you need to perform specific actions when your app is closed, you might need to combine this approach with monitoring other lifecycle states like AppLifecycleState.paused or AppLifecycleState.inactive.

Hi Bob, How can we detect if my app was closed from recent apps using AppLifecycleState.paused or AppLifecycleState.inactive? Since AppLifecycleState.paused triggered while switching the app too. If possible can you please share me the sample code.

What is your use case. I am also working on same thing

Hi @Vikas, I have to clear browser cookies when the app is closed from the login page.

try to use state == AppLifecycleState.resumand state == AppLifecycleState.paused example -
   @override
      void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        if (state == state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
          // App was closed from recent tabs
        } if (state == state == AppLifecycleState.resum) {
          // App was closed from recent tabs
        }
      }


Hi Pasindu Kaushalya, Thanks for your response. Your workaround won't work because AppLifecycleState.paused was initiated during the app switch, and AppLifecycleState.resume was initiated upon reopening the app from the list of recently opened apps. I would like to know the exact moment the app was closed.

When the application closes, you can use the shared preferences and current time log to share shared information (such as a timestamp). You can obtain an app destroy time when you open the app again.

Hi @Pasindu, How can we achieve this using Shared Preferences? Can you please give me a detailed explanation? If possible share the sample code.
